# How to access root element of child component in parent component in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I do know about defineExpose function, but it seems to be a bad practice, so I'm looking for proper solution which may help me.
Answering a question in advance - yes, I really need in since there is v-for in my parent component with dynamic component imports for each iteration which I pass to the  element in :is attribute.
I need to implement custom drag and drop logic so I need root HTML element of child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need root HTML element you can assign a [ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs) to your component, which is accessable once the component is mounted, and the HTML itself is on `refName.value.$el`

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="Child" ref="myComp" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import Child from '@/components/Child.vue';
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

const myComp = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(myComp.value.$el);
});
</script>
```

Comment: In Vue 3 child component instanse in not exposed by default.

Comment: your question mentioned needing root HTML element.  so you need access to its functions/data properties?

Comment: No, I need exactly root element of child component, but it is not available if you do not use defineExpose function in child which exposes ref with root element, you can check it by yourself

Comment: In other words, if you just add ref to a child component in parent component, nothing from child component will be available including root elem

Comment: I did check, you can get the physical DOM element using the code provided in my answer, just not the functions/data properties from `<script setup>` which is what [defineExpose](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose) is for. The DOM is not private and can't be made inaccessible by Vue. If you wanted to you could get the root element with simple vanilla js and document.querySelector, I'm just providing the more "Vue-centric" way of doing it with `ref`